# Are there non-continuous kernels?

Tags: reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

In Mercer's theorem context, the kernel has to be a continuous function. But if you look at the RKHS theory, the kernel does not have to be continuous.

Is it possible to find a symmetric, positive semidefinite kernel which is **non-continuous**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are non-continuous positive semi-definite kernels. One actually useful example is the kernel
\begin{equation} K(x,y)=
\begin{cases} 1, & \text{ if } x=y \\ 
0, & \text{ if }x\neq y.
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}
This is positive definite as it is the covariance function of the Gaussian white noise process, i.e. independent unit normal. Adding this kernel to a continuous one is the standard way to include noise/uncertainty in Gaussian process regression.